# How to select a region of GPS coordinates from multiple tracks?

Tags: java, algorithm, gps, machine-learning

I have multiple GPS tracks(vector of 2d latitude, longitude coordinates) that I have created using my mobile device. They have different lengths and directions. I want to average this tracks and create just a single one. As a first step I would like to select only the points that are in a certain area. For example in the image bellow I want to select only the points that are between the grey lines.

[image]

Given the fact that the tracks might have different shapes and positioning would a bounding rectangle approach make sense? Are there better algorithms to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look into these classes for practical use :

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/clustering/DBSCANClusterer.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/filter.html

Comment: If I have some very long tracks, and each track has points that are approximately at the same length, would DBSCAN create one cluster with all this points or would there be multiple clusters created?

Comment: Your DBSCANClusterer  constructor parameters will define number of clusters according to your points: eps: the distance that defines the ε-neighborhood of a point, minPoints: the minimum number of density-connected points required to form a cluster

Comment: Ok. After some tests I can safely say that I got good results with this method.

Answer (score 1):

I would try clustering points from multiple tracks. After that, I would use the center point of each cluster to get my *average* path.

For clustering, you can use kNN or any other principle where you group points that are near each other.

After getting your *average* path, you can apply bounds to it (you could also filter your points before clustering).